# SQLAlchemy Multitype columns - Hybrid Property querying

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqldatatypes, composite, hybrid

I have several tables in my PostgreSQL database that need to contain timeseries like information in an IoT-link context, that require several data types supported for the value of each point in the series, like this:

```
class Telemetry(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ts_kv"

    key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bool_v = Column(Boolean)
    str_v = Column(String)
    long_v = Column(BigInteger)
    dbl_v = Column(DOUBLE_PRECISION)
    json_v = Column(JSON)
    ts = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    entity_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

I need to parse an incoming model from a REST API that has a single *value* field which can be any of the above types. I can parse the input data type correctly into the corresponding column with no issues.

The problem arises when I try to query the table for a given *value*, without directly specifying the data type, I would need to achieve  something like this:

```
data = session.query(Telemetry.ts, Telemetry.value).filter(Telemetry.value == MY_MULTITYPE_VALUE).all()
```

I've tried using *hybrid properties* and *hybrid methods* like below:

```
@hybrid_property
def value(self):
    return self.str_v if self.str_v else (
        self.dbl_v if self.dbl_v else (
            self.bool_v if self.bool_v else (
                self.json_v if self.json_v else self.long_v
            )
        )
    )


@value.expression
def value(self):
    return self.str_v if self.str_v else (
        self.dbl_v if self.dbl_v else (
            self.bool_v if self.bool_v else (
                self.json_v if self.json_v else self.long_v
            )
        )
    )
```

The first part of the operation works correctly, as if I query:

```
session.query(Telemetry.value).filter(ANY FILTER).all()
```

I do get correct values. However, querying like in the following example fails, because the *expression* for value evaluates always *true* for the first part of the conditional, IE: *if self.str_v* yields always *True* as it evals the COLUMN as existing, not the actual value for the row in that column. I've also tried using the *func* and *not_*/*is_null* operators with the exact same result.

```
a = session.query(Telemetry).filter(Telemetry.value == 55).first() #Always fails because long_v is behind in the expression evaluation.
```

How can I achieve this behaviour in the simplest fashion? I've looked into composite columns but couldn't figure out a way to properly handle the parsing/de-parsing.

Comment: The `expression` needs to be an SQL statement. You can solve this using `CASE` In the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rfkortekaas correctly pointed out in his comment, the *expression* needs to be SQL. And *if/else* don't qualify.

```
from sqlalchemy import case

@hybrid_property
def value(self):
    return self.str_v if self.str_v is not None else (
        self.long_v if self.long_v is not None else (
            self.dbl_v if self.dbl_v is not None else self.bool_v
        )
    )

@value.expression
def value(cls):
    return case(
        (cls.str_v.is_not(None), cls.str_v),
        (cls.dbl_v.is_not(None), cls.dbl_v),
        (cls.long_v.is_not(None), cls.long_v),
        else_=cls.bool_v
    )
```